# How to select month's fee where month is selected by user

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to PHP and I am trying to develop a student management system with two tables:

```
1.student_details_tbl 

2.student_fees_tbl
```

In **student_details_tbl** all details of students are saved and in the **student_fees_tbl** table, details of which students have paid their month's fees are saved.

My problem is that I wanted a list of students who have not paid their fees for the user selected month.

**student_detais_tbl** has the following fields:

```
id  student_id name   age  address  contact  image
```

**student_fees_tbl** has the following fields:

```
id   student_id month   type  amount
```

Comment: can u show the code which you've tried.

Comment: the main query for selecting students is  select DISTINCT a.s_id,a.name,b.month from students_tbl a left join  fees_tbl b on a.s_id=b.s_id where n.month!='$month' how ever this query also select student who paid their fees for given month

Comment: is student_fees table has the entries of student who has paid fess ?? or entries of all the students with amount 0??

Comment: only student who paid their fees

Comment: wait a minute... @MohdAsif

Comment: Hi once try with this query..
`SELECT d.id,d.student_id,f.student_id as paid_stu,d.name,f.month FROM `student_details_tbl` as d LEFT JOIN `student_fees_tbl` as f ON d.student_id = f.student_id WHERE d.student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM student_fees_tbl WHERE month = '4')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY this query ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM student_detais_tbl 
WHERE id NOT IN( SELECT A.student_id  
         FROM student_fees_tbl  A
         JOIN student_detais_tbl  B 
         ON  A.student_id = B.id AND A.month='Month'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM student_details_tbl 
WHERE student_id NOT IN(SELECT student_id from student_fees_tbl where month='Month')
```

Is there any problem with this query